# How to reflect the tick value in tooltip content in Google charts (Bubble Chart)

Tags: angular, charts, google-visualization, xticks

I am using Angular Google charts library. As per the official documentation, the value of x axis can only be a number. I wanted to plot the graph by string, hence i used `hAxis.tick` which changes the horizontal axis plot to string very well. However this is not reflecting the tooltip, the tooltip still shows a number.

Any way using which I can map the value in the ticks to the tooltip content.

Below is the sample snippet code for HTML

```
<google-chart
      title="Bubble Chart"
      type="BubbleChart"
      [data]="plotData"
      [options]="bubbleChartoptions"
      [columns]="bubbleColumnNames"
      [width]="550"
      [height]="350"
    >
    </google-chart>
```

Also, the ts file contains the following data which is used to plot the data

```
bubbleColumnNames:['ToDisplay', 'hAxisValue', 'vAxisValue','bubbleType','size'] 


plotData: [
            ['', 1, 3, 'Bubble1', 10],
            ['', 1, 8, 'Bubble2', 20],
            ['', 2, 3, 'Bubble1', 30],
            ['', 2, 4, 'Bubble2', 40],
            ['', 3, 6, 'Bubble1', 50],
            ['', 3, 7, 'Bubble2', 60],
            ['', 4, 7, 'Bubble1', 70],
            ['', 4, 7, 'Bubble2', 80],
          ],
bubbleChartoptions = {
  hAxis: {
  ticks: [{  v: 1, f:'param1'}, {v: 2, f:'param2'}, {v: 3, f:'param3'}],
}
```

Ideally the tooltip should show param1 corresponding to `hAxisValue`, but it shows `1`

Thanks!

Comment: will you please share the code used to draw the chart?

Comment: @WhiteHat I have modified the question above to reflect the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the tooltip will display the formatted value of the x-axis by default.

much like the ticks you are generating,
we can supply the formatted value in the data using object notation...

```
plotData: [
  ['', {v: 1, f: 'param1'}, 3, 'Bubble1', 10],
  ['', {v: 1, f: 'param1'}, 8, 'Bubble2', 20],
  ['', {v: 2, f: 'param2'}, 3, 'Bubble1', 30],
  ['', {v: 2, f: 'param2'}, 4, 'Bubble2', 40],
  ['', {v: 3, f: 'param3'}, 6, 'Bubble1', 50],
  ['', {v: 3, f: 'param3'}, 7, 'Bubble2', 60],
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! it worked. Also is there a way we can remove the x-axis key value pair from the tooltip? @WhiteHat

Comment: it might be possible using a custom tooltip, though the data format for a bubble chart does not include the tooltip role. [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62457162/5090771) for a different chart type...

Comment: ohh,any way we can do this in bubble chart?

Comment: found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62281683/5090771), which I think will work for your needs, let me know...

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but this seems to be working for google charts, I am using a different library i.e. angular-google-charts and i don't see these classes there.

Comment: they should produce the same result, but first, you have to set the following option --> `tooltip: {isHtml: true}`